# in sql how to write sub query which provides two value in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I use mysql.
Here is my sql

```
select *
from releases
where  id >
(
    select min(id) as x
    from releases 
    where released > "2011-12-01"
) 
limit 0,30
```

This is right.
But I want to find items which id are in the range(not only greater than) like this:

```
select *
from releases
where  id >
    ((
        select min(id) as x , max(id) as y
        from releases 
        where released > "2011-12-01"
    ) as D ) D.x and id < D.y
limit 0,30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
select 
    *
from 
    releases,
    (select 
        min(id) as x, 
        max(id) as y
     from
        releases
     where released > "2011-12-01"
     ) as D   
where
    id between D.x and D.y
limit 0,30
```

Comment: Thank you ,But looks like using two tables? They will do cross product?

Comment: Nope, it should'nt. Return here if it would

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM releases r 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) minId, MAX(id) maxId FROM releases WHERE released > '2011-12-01') AS A ON r.id BETWEEN A.minId AND A.maxId 
LIMIT 0,30;
```

Comment: Thank you ,But using join means using two tables? They will do cross product?

Comment: Use Explain keyword to check the how many rows were scanned. No they won't do cross product